# Sort a Grouped Dictionary array in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, sorting, swiftui, group-by

I am making a chat app in SwiftUI. I am having issue in sorting the array by the date created. I have a **dictionary array**. I am trying to sort the array by date in the ascending order, but not getting the desired result.

This is my array:

> let dictionaryArray : [String : [Message]] = ["23-06-2023": [Message(id: "-NYcL3a30OY1XA4Lhnw-", senderName: "Zain", senderPersonalId: "13", senderFirebaseId: "gQvArR1htjQOehdtcmOuAtg6WrY2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "23-06-2023 18:01:20", message: "Helo", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text"), Message(id: "-NYcM_usuveQfshnzcH2", senderName: "Zain", senderPersonalId: "13", senderFirebaseId: "gQvArR1htjQOehdtcmOuAtg6WrY2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "23-06-2023 18:07:58", message: "What's up?", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text")], "24-06-2023": [Message(id: "-NYcKd2XYeOJ1FCw0Kveds", senderName: "Shair Ali", senderPersonalId: "24", senderFirebaseId: "moyVNv1UMlVcJgjtzB45oieJupi1", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "24-06-2023 17:59:27", message: "Are you free", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text")], "05-07-2023": [Message(id: "-NZ_-_eGUb3siyLXw51c", senderName: "Taimoor", senderPersonalId: "16", senderFirebaseId: "dYXbzxfwxrZLQ366vkjtfFXqSHE2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "05-07-2023 12:44:18", message: "Hi", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text"), Message(id: "-NZ_KFDQVWDA391kpK7h", senderName: "Taimoor", senderPersonalId: "16", senderFirebaseId: "dYXbzxfwxrZLQ366vkjtfFXqSHE2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "05-07-2023 14:14:35", message: "What are you doing?", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text")]]

These are my Models:

```
struct GroupedMessages: Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id = UUID()
  var date: String?
  var messages: [Message]
}

struct Message: Identifiable, Hashable {

    var id : String
    var senderName: String
    var senderPersonalId: String
    var senderFirebaseId: String
    var messageId: String
    var sentDate: String
    var message: String
    var seenMessage: String
    var isGroupChat: String
    var isBusinessChat: String
    var recieverFirebaseId: String
    var recieverFirebaseName: String
    var recieverPersonalID: String
    var type: String
}
```

And this is the code to sort the array:

```
      let msgs = dictionaryArray.map { key, value in
            let messages = value.sorted { $0.sentDate < $1.sentDate }
            return GroupedMessages(date: key, messages: messages
      }
            
      let groupMessages = msgs.sorted(by: { $0.date! < $1.date! })
                
      debugPrint(groupMessages)
```

This results in:

[image]

Here **05-07-2023** is the latest date but it is at the start of the array. This should be the last index of the array as this is the biggest date. The remaining two dates **23-06-2023** and **24-06-2023** are fine. I am having this issue when the month changes.

What would I need to fix in my code to make the array in ascending order?

Comment: `"23-06-2023"` is not a "sortable" format by simple comparison with `<`. Since it compares the day first. If it where `"2023-06-23"`, it would have been ok. Convert it into a `Date` first.

Comment: @Larme ok, let me convert it to **Date** first.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
struct Message: Identifiable, Hashable {

var id : String
var senderName: String
var senderPersonalId: String
var senderFirebaseId: String
var messageId: String
var sentDate: Date
var message: String
var seenMessage: String
var isGroupChat: String
var isBusinessChat: String
var recieverFirebaseId: String
var recieverFirebaseName: String
var recieverPersonalID: String
var type: String

init(id: String, senderName: String, senderPersonalId: String, senderFirebaseId: String, messageId: String, sentDate: String, message: String, seenMessage: String, isGroupChat: String, isBusinessChat: String, recieverFirebaseId: String, recieverFirebaseName: String, recieverPersonalID: String, type: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.senderName = senderName
    self.senderPersonalId = senderPersonalId
    self.senderFirebaseId = senderFirebaseId
    self.messageId = messageId
    
    self.sentDate = convertDateString(dateStr: sentDate)
    
    self.message = message
    self.seenMessage = seenMessage
    self.isGroupChat = isGroupChat
    self.isBusinessChat = isBusinessChat
    self.recieverFirebaseId = recieverFirebaseId
    self.recieverFirebaseName = recieverFirebaseName
    self.recieverPersonalID = recieverPersonalID
    self.type = type
}

func tempValue()
{
    let dictionaryArray : [String : [Message]] = ["23-06-2023": [Message(id: "-NYcL3a30OY1XA4Lhnw-", senderName: "Zain", senderPersonalId: "13", senderFirebaseId: "gQvArR1htjQOehdtcmOuAtg6WrY2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "23-06-2023 18:01:20", message: "Helo", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text"), Message(id: "-NYcM_usuveQfshnzcH2", senderName: "Zain", senderPersonalId: "13", senderFirebaseId: "gQvArR1htjQOehdtcmOuAtg6WrY2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "23-06-2023 18:07:58", message: "What's up?", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text")], "24-06-2023": [Message(id: "-NYcKd2XYeOJ1FCw0Kveds", senderName: "Shair Ali", senderPersonalId: "24", senderFirebaseId: "moyVNv1UMlVcJgjtzB45oieJupi1", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "24-06-2023 17:59:27", message: "Are you free", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text")], "05-07-2023": [Message(id: "-NZ_-_eGUb3siyLXw51c", senderName: "Taimoor", senderPersonalId: "16", senderFirebaseId: "dYXbzxfwxrZLQ366vkjtfFXqSHE2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "05-07-2023 12:44:18", message: "Hi", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text"), Message(id: "-NZ_KFDQVWDA391kpK7h", senderName: "Taimoor", senderPersonalId: "16", senderFirebaseId: "dYXbzxfwxrZLQ366vkjtfFXqSHE2", messageId: "Group_Mlb group_24_23-06-2023 17:59:27", sentDate: "05-07-2023 14:14:35", message: "What are you doing?", seenMessage: "false", isGroupChat: "true", isBusinessChat: "false", recieverFirebaseId: "nil", recieverFirebaseName: "Mlb group", recieverPersonalID: "0", type: "text")]]
    
    
    let msgs = dictionaryArray.map { key, value in
        
        let messages = value.sorted { $0.sentDate.compare($1.sentDate) == .orderedDescending }
        
        return GroupedMessages(date: key, messages: messages)
    }
    print(msgs)
}}
```

Use this function to convert string to date

```
 func convertDateString(dateStr: String) -> Date
   {
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    
    let dateValue = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
    return dateValue!
}
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response but Larme's answer worked in my case